# Making Django CategoryProperty from Table in GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to use the following category function to pull in names from a DB table and populate the categories with names from a pre-existing table. I.e. how can I use, or even if it is possible?

```
companycategory = db.CategoryProperty
```

I have no idea how to do this or whether this is possible in GAE. What I was proposing was using the following example https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling with the contacts and telephone numbers, but whenever I try this approach when rendering the page I cannot get the names from the Table into the drop down box without displaying the object.

I am trying:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    companyurl = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companyname = db.StringProperty(required=False)

class CompanyCategory(db.Model):
    categoryname = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    company = db.ReferenceProperty(Company, collection_name='categories')
```

What would the smartest way of doing this be? To summarize I want to have multiple categories possible for each company and have those categories stored in table rather than hard coded. And to make work with Django! Am I asking too much?

## Part II

Here is a little bit more of an explanation:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    companyurl = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    companyname = db.StringProperty(required=False)


class CompanyCategory(db.Model):
    categoryname = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    company = db.ReferenceProperty(Company, collection_name='categories')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % (self.categoryname)
```

I want to have within the Company Data structure a way of storing and selecting categories which are themselves listed in a Table in the DataStore. So one row might have Internet, another "Bank" listed in the Table name CompanyCategory. The model is above.

How do I link the Company Model to the category model in such a way that the drop down is populated in Django? All the examples have no way of linking such that the Company has a category option. Apologies if I am missing something

Comment: No idea what you mean about categories, but if you define a `__unicode__` function on your Company model that should show up in the dropdown.

Comment: @DanielRoseman do you mean like this: `code`class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name) `code`

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I can't seem to find any documentation on this, but how do I get the drop downs populated when rendering the Company Model. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated things above to reflect the unicode changes.

Comment: I don't understand your edit or your question. The company model doesn't have a dropdown - companycategory does.

Comment: @DanielRoseman When rendering the Django form for company, I'd like the drop downs to be selected from the table of companycategories. It's this aspect that I don't know how to work. How do I create that drop-down for the company category?

Comment: It's still the case that the company model **doesn't have any dropdowns**. Dropdowns, by which I assume you mean select inputs, are rendered for ReferenceProperties, to allow you to choose which item to reference. In the models as you posted them above, Company does not have a ReferenceProperty. The only one you have shown is from CompanyCategory *pointing at* company. That means it will display when you are editing CompanyCategory, and will be populated with a list of companies, formatted by the `__unicode__` method of Company. If that's not what you want, you should alter your models.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have altered the model, I was pointing the wrong way. My fault and now fixed. However I cannot get the drop downs working right when adding a Company to the data store which has a cateogry. The values are not populated in the table right.